# _tcslen becomes a call to _mbslen even with _UNICODE & _MBCS not defined

Tags: c, winapi, unicode, widechar, cl

First time SO user here.

I'm trying to get a better understanding of Unicode, utf-8 and the like. And at the moment I'm doing it from the Windows command prompt.

Is it alright to post a dump of the disassembly as seen in Visual Studio?

```
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

#ifdef _UNICODE
UC = 0x1;
#else
UC = 0x2;
#endif

#ifdef _MBCS
UM = 0x4;
#else
UM = 0x8;
#endif

int main()
{
00007FF65B276270 40 56                push        rsi  
00007FF65B276272 57                   push        rdi  
00007FF65B276273 48 83 EC 78          sub         rsp,78h  
00007FF65B276277 48 8B 05 B2 2D 01 00 mov         rax,qword ptr [__security_cookie (07FF65B289030h)]  
00007FF65B27627E 48 33 C4             xor         rax,rsp  
00007FF65B276281 48 89 44 24 68       mov         qword ptr [rsp+68h],rax  
    UINT cs = UC | UM;
00007FF65B276286 8B 05 78 43 01 00    mov         eax,dword ptr [UM (07FF65B28A604h)]  
00007FF65B27628C 8B 0D 6E 43 01 00    mov         ecx,dword ptr [UC (07FF65B28A600h)]  
00007FF65B276292 0B C8                or          ecx,eax  
00007FF65B276294 8B C1                mov         eax,ecx  
00007FF65B276296 89 44 24 38          mov         dword ptr [cs],eax  
    TCHAR streng[] = TEXT("aæbøcådÆeØfÅg");
00007FF65B27629A 48 8D 44 24 40       lea         rax,[streng]  
00007FF65B27629F 48 8D 0D 62 43 01 00 lea         rcx,[UM+4h (07FF65B28A608h)]  
00007FF65B2762A6 48 8B F8             mov         rdi,rax  
00007FF65B2762A9 48 8B F1             mov         rsi,rcx  
00007FF65B2762AC B9 28 00 00 00       mov         ecx,28h  
00007FF65B2762B1 F3 A4                rep movs    byte ptr [rdi],byte ptr [rsi]  
    HANDLE hConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
00007FF65B2762B3 B9 F5 FF FF FF       mov         ecx,0FFFFFFF5h  
00007FF65B2762B8 FF 15 42 9D 01 00    call        qword ptr [__imp_GetStdHandle (07FF65B290000h)]  
00007FF65B2762BE 48 89 44 24 30       mov         qword ptr [hConsoleOutput],rax  
    WriteConsole(hConsoleOutput, streng, _tcslen(streng), 0, 0);
00007FF65B2762C3 48 8D 4C 24 40       lea         rcx,[streng]  
00007FF65B2762C8 E8 6F B1 FE FF       call        _mbslen (07FF65B26143Ch)  
00007FF65B2762CD 48 C7 44 24 20 00 00 00 00 mov         qword ptr [rsp+20h],0  
00007FF65B2762D6 45 33 C9             xor         r9d,r9d  
00007FF65B2762D9 44 8B C0             mov         r8d,eax  
00007FF65B2762DC 48 8D 54 24 40       lea         rdx,[streng]  
00007FF65B2762E1 48 8B 4C 24 30       mov         rcx,qword ptr [hConsoleOutput]  
00007FF65B2762E6 FF 15 1C 9D 01 00    call        qword ptr [__imp_WriteConsoleW (07FF65B290008h)]  
    return 0;
00007FF65B2762EC 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
}
00007FF65B2762EE 48 8B 4C 24 68       mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+68h]  
00007FF65B2762F3 48 33 CC             xor         rcx,rsp  
00007FF65B2762F6 E8 55 AE FE FF       call        __security_check_cookie (07FF65B261150h)  
00007FF65B2762FB 48 83 C4 78          add         rsp,78h  
00007FF65B2762FF 5F                   pop         rdi  
00007FF65B276300 5E                   pop         rsi  
00007FF65B276301 C3                   ret
```

I can't figure out why `_tcslen(streng)` is compiled into a call to `_mbslen` when [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx) states that _mbslen is only used when _MBCS is defined.

I compile with `cl -Zi main.c` and when I `devenv main.exe` I can confirm that neither _UNICODE nor _MBCS is defined with the line `UINT cs = UC | UM;` (cs is 0xa).

If I remove the first line where I define UNICODE and I set the codepage in the Command prompt to 65001 it all works fine because I save the source file with utf-8. And if I keep the UNICODE define but hardcode `wcslen(streng)` and code points in the string it also works. Which leads me to believe that even if _tcslen became wcslen it wouldn't work unless I hardcode the Unicode code point into the string. But that's not really the point. I want to know why the compiler chooses to call _mbslen instead of wcslen.

Comment: "neither _UNICODE nor _MBCS is defined"  That's a problem.  You *want* `_UNICODE` defined.  Also, I can't understand how that code even compiles, since you have assignment statements at file scope.

Comment: Can you post disassembly corresponding to calls to `strlen`, `_mbslen`, and `wcslen` ?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Implicit int (plus a common compiler extension). One reason to enable warnings (at least `/W3`). Another one that even could be the answer to the question is that `<tchar.h>` wasn't included which causes `_tcslen()` to be implicitly declared. And if that isn't already bad enough, the (debug) static link library probably contains a symbol called `__tcslen`.

Comment: All the same, you don't want to use tchar anymore, unless you target Windows 98.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm reading Petzold 5th Ed. so that's why I write in legacy mode. The book has no mention of UTF-8 hence my own research into the matter.

Comment: @BenVoigt Including <tchar.h> helped tremendously. That and using -W4 when compiling which revealed some issues. Thanks alot! It might be some stupid mistakes, but I'm wiser and that's all that counts for me.

Comment: You really don't want to use tchar.

Comment: Understood. Just trying to learn. But I had hoped that I could use unicode characters in my source files. It is so much easier to read L"aæbøcådÆeØfÅg" than L"a\u00E6b\u00F8c\u00E5d\u00C6e\u00D8f\u00C5g".

Comment: That's a different issue completely. MSVC does support Unicode source, either utf8 or utf16. Utterly unrelated to tchar.